# AWS private elastic ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy, elastic-ip

I have a scenario where I want to setup an haproxy cluster with keepalived. I saw this blog post https://www.peternijssen.nl/high-availability-haproxy-keepalived-aws/ and its pretty detailed and easy to follow, but for my scenario I need the elastic IP's to be private. Is this doable ? As from AWS documentation Elastic IP's are only public IPs.

I need a floating IP which will act as a floating cluster IP. What can I use if Elastic IP is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

An elastic IP within AWS is actually a static public IP address. This functionality is required as by default a public IP address is not reserved by an account, and when enabled limits the total IPv4 addresses you can keep.

For private address ranges however, your instances can be assigned any private IP address that is within any of your VPCs CIDR range(s).

In fact for this reason you can select almost any IP address found within your VPC when launching a new instance, in addition the IP addresses that are attached to an EC2 instance are static and will be attached to that instance until it is terminated.

Therefore as long as you don't terminate the instances the private IP(s) will be maintained. However, in the event the instance fails and is not recoverable you would still need to launch a new instance and use that IP.

It might be more beneficial using a DNS record to resolve the IP just in case of an emergency, or failing that use a load balancer to distribute traffic.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you can provision an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) with a static private IP address which you can attach/re-attach to EC2 instances. As long as you don’t delete the ENI, it will retain the I  as p address. Find out more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html